# CellForItemAt: index path not updating variable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working with a UITableView that has a cell with a UISwitch in it.  I have four tableViewCells, each from this same prototype cell. However, when I toggle the switch, the only way that the variables in the TableView `CellForItemAt:` section is when I pull the tableView so that it goes out of the screen, and the Reusable Cells are Reloaded. How can I make these variables refresh when the switches are toggled?

Here is my code:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "onOffCell", for: indexPath) as! SettingsCellTableViewCell


    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = OLLItems![indexPath.row]._text
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            GlobalData.AllGlobalData.OLLImageState = cell.state //GlobalData.AllGlobalData.OLLImageState is an struct in another file
            print("OLLImageState \(GlobalData.AllGlobalData.OLLImageState)")




        }
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            GlobalData.AllGlobalData.OLLAlgState = cell.state
            print("OLLAlgState \(GlobalData.AllGlobalData.OLLAlgState)")

        }

    }
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = PLLItems![indexPath.row]._text
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            GlobalData.AllGlobalData.PLLImageState = cell.state
            print("PLLImageState \(GlobalData.AllGlobalData.PLLImageState)")



        }
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            GlobalData.AllGlobalData.PLLAlgState = cell.state 
            print("PLLAlgState \(GlobalData.AllGlobalData.PLLAlgState)")

        }

    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Never read data from a cell, especially in `cellForRowAt`. Read data from your data model.

Comment: Where would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

### Try doing it this way

> Below code works properly in my repo but I changed it a bit to justify your scenario

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "switchCell", for: indexPath) as! SwitchContainingTableViewCell

        cell.mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return cell
    }

    func switchChanged(_ mySwitch: UISwitch) {

      guard let cell = mySwitch.superview?.superview as? SwitchContainingTableViewCell else {
          return // or fatalError() or whatever
      }

      self.value = mySwitch.isOn   //define var value in your controller or do it locally 

      let indexPath = itemTable.indexPath(for: cell)        

      if indexPath.section == 0 {
          if indexPath.row == 0 {
               GlobalData.AllGlobalData.OLLImageState = self.value
          }
      }
    }
```

I have added a target of the `switch` and in the target I'm getting the changed state of the switch. The same can be done within the `cellForItemAt:` by using `state = mySwitch.isOn`

Hope this helps!

Comment: As per your comment you are trying to add the target to cell (cell.addTarget) instead you have to add the target to your switch (cell.mySwitch.addTarget). Targets are added so that you can monitor the change/modification for the UI objects.